# Use case to Pause a flow salesforce

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, process

I have gone thru many links but couldn't understand when would a user click on "Pause" button on flow? What could be a real scenario where we may have to Pause a flow. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pausing the flow saves the current state of the flow for later execution. This allows them to resume their work later without starting from the beginning. Reasons why they might want to save include going to lunch, leaving the office at the end of the day, dealing with a forced device restart (e.g. Windows Update or computer slowness), or some unexpected event where they might need to leave their computer for an extended period of time and might be logged out.

Comment: To add on, this is also potentially useful in the B2B checkout flows where the customer starts the flow, goes and does something else, then comes back and continues where they left off.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.